# How can I dynamically add working buttons to my incremental reward system in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

[Here](http://jsbin.com/OGULEVU) is the link 
I managed to get my buttons work like I want them to, to increase the number of 'Points' by 50 on each click, and every time the 'Points' reach another 500, the 'Level' increases by one.

If I were to use this as a To-Do List, how could I keep adding buttons, like the ones already coded in, but dynamically. Instead of coding the buttons in to the HTML, I'd much prefer being able to add more buttons, with the title of my choice (text input?). I'd hope they were all similar in style. (I'm using bootstrap CSS).

If possible for me to choose how many points each button gives.

I have absolutely no clue on how to do this, can someone please help me out? Thank you in advance.

Also, how can I send the 'Points' and 'Levels', as well as all the created buttons to a text file, so that when I refresh the page, nothing's changed? Thank you again.

Here is the same code used in the JSbin link above.

HTML

```
<center>
  <h2>Reward System</h2>
  </br>
<div class='well' style="width:400px;">
<input type='button' value='Task 1' onClick='add()' class='btn btn-danger'> 
<span class="label label-default">+50</span>
</div>

<div class='well' style="width:400px;">

<input type='button' value='Task 2' onClick='add()' class='btn btn-danger'>
<span class="label label-default">+50</span>
</div>

<div class='well' style="width:400px;">

<input type='button' value='Task 3' onClick='add()' class='btn btn-danger'>
<span class="label label-default">+50</span>
</div>

<div class='well' style="width:400px;">

<input type='button' value='Task 4' onClick='add()' class='btn btn-danger'>
<span class="label label-default">+50</span>
</div>


</br></br>

<hr style="width:400px;">


<div>
  <h3>Points </h3>
  <p id='p'>0</p>
</div>

<hr style="width:400px;">

<div  style="width:400px;">
  <h3>Level 
  <p id='lvl'>0</p>

</div>

<hr style="width:400px;">

</center>
```

Javascript

```
var i = 0;
var lvl = 0;
var a = 100;

function add() {
   i+=50;
  document.getElementById('p').innerHTML = i;
var perc = ' "' + ' "px';
var para = document.getElementById("p");
para.style.fontSize = perc;

  while (i > 5*a) {
    lvl+=1;
    a+=100;
}

  document.getElementById('lvl').innerHTML = lvl;
  var perc1= ' "' + ' "px';
var para1= document.getElementById("lvl");
  para1style.fontSize = perc1;

}
```

Comment: Regarding the file part, you can save the data in browser localStorage instead of writing it into a file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give the new buttons the same class as the other ones.

```
var newBtn = document.createElement('button');
newBtn.className = 'btn';
```

To add click Listener you can attach to them before appending them:

```
newBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    addToResult(this.getAttribute('data-points'));
});
```

I've added an attribute to the buttons called `data-points` which stores the points clicking that button will give. It'd be more appropriate this way than getting it from a sibling span, but the span is rather to show user.

**Edited code:**

```
var addBtn = document.getElementById('addBtn');
addBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var container = document.getElementById('container');
    var btnName = document.getElementById('btnName').value;
    var btnPoints = parseInt(document.getElementById('btnPoints').value);
    if(!btnName)
        btnName = "Button ?";
    if(!btnPoints)
        btnPoints = 50;
    var newBtn = document.createElement('button');
    var newPnt = document.createElement('span');
    newBtn.className = 'btn';
    newBtn.innerText = btnName;
    newBtn.setAttribute('data-points', btnPoints);
    newBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
        addToResult(this.getAttribute('data-points'));
    });
    newPnt.className = 'label';
    newPnt.innerText = "+" + btnPoints;
    container.appendChild(newBtn);
    container.appendChild(newPnt);
});
```

[**Updated jsfiddle DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/skacbc8d/8/)

**EDIT 2:**

To remove and element you use: `element.parentNode.removeChild(element)`. So to put it into context, you'll need to remove the associated span as well:

```
newBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    addToResult(this.getAttribute('data-points'));
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this.nextElementSibling);
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
});
```

**EDIT#N:**

It's fairly simple to use localStorage. To save the result:

```
var result = document.getElementById('result').innerText;
localStorage.setItem("whateverName", result);
```

And whenever you want to get it back:

```
localStorage.getItem("whateverName");
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried to add your code to my script and now I can name them, they have the same class and are generated above one another. A few questions. 

How would I add the onClick function to each button? I tried
newBtn.onClick = 'add()'; 
But it didn't work.

Also, how can I generate each button inside of a well, and have the "+50" badge on it's right?

Thank you again!

Comment: Added how to add click listener + addToResult function so you can see they work and add the given points. Now also you can give each new button a separate point. If you find the answer useful, please vote it up and choose as best answer.

Comment: Wow, you've really helped me out a lot. Thank you so much! I know I'm being greedy but I was wondering if you could tell me how to make the button disappear once it's been clicked?

Comment: Would you be able to show me how to save the results into the local storage of the browser pls

Comment: Where do I enter in the code? I tried in many different places but it's still not working? I also tried to look at some examples online but I still don't get it. Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77386/discussion-between-samurai-and-samir-chahine).

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the file part, you can save the data in browser localStorage instead of writing it into a file

to save something:

```
localStorage.setItem("param1",param1Value);
```

to get it (after loading the page again, on load):

```
var param1Value = localStorage.getItem("param1");
```

regard the add task, I've added [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/8fcya6t6/) but it uses jQuery (which is very recommended for your tasks..) hope that's help

```
<div><button id="addTaskButton" class="btn">Add Task</button></div>


$("#addTaskButton").click(function (event) {
    var nextNumber = $(".well").length + 1;
    $($("hr")[0]).before("<div class='well' style='width:400px;'><input type='button' value='Task " + nextNumber + "' onClick='add()' class='btn btn-danger'> <span class='label label-default'>+50</span></div>");
});
```

Press 'Add Task' button will add you a new task button..

Answer (score 1):

```
// Creating an element:
var newDiv = document.createElement('div');

// Changing attributes of an element:
newDiv.setAttribute('class','desiredClass');

// Changing the innerHTML of the element:
newDiv.innerHTML = 'Desired inner HTML';


// Finally - Append the new element somewhere in the DOM (HTML Tree):
document.getElementsById('SomeID').appendChild(newDiv);
```

Comment: If you don't mind, can you please show me how I'd use your lines of code in mine? Thank you!